# WPF ListBoxItem IsSelected property selects only for an instant

Tags: wpf

I have a `ListBoxItem` template with a `TextBox` element within. When the user clicks the `TextBox`, I should make the `ListBoxItem` as the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DockPanel Margin="4,0,4,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value1, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ToolTip="{Binding Path=Hint, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox x:Name="TextField"                              
                          Margin="2,0,0,0"
                          Width="{Binding Path=ActWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                          Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibleAct, Mode=OneWay}"
                          />
        </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I have the following Trigger to make the selection:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.Resources>
```

Unfortunately, it works only for 
an instant, *when I change the focus, the selection disappears*.
If I remove the trigger, it works normally but selecting the `TextBox` does not trigger the selection.

What should I do to make the selection permanent?

Comment: @mm8 I modified the initial post. No, I want to select only 1 item, but keep the selection. As I mentioned, if I don't use the trigger, and select the item manually, it works.

Comment: By clicking another control in the containing UserControl.

Comment: Try adding default setter for IsSelected, and make it value = binding IsSelected, oneWay, relativeSource self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample doesn't work because, if the trigger is false, your `ListBoxItem` is getting the value as it had before triggering. Your `ListBoxItem` is like 'ehmm, what I was..'.

So you have to set its `SelectedValue` by adding a default setter that binds its `IsSelected` state:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode="OneWay", RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Setting default setter for `IsSelected` as `OneWay` binding to itself will do the job. It will set `IsSelected` as it was, when the trigger is false.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some code to set the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox`. You could handle the `GotKeyboardFocus` event for the `TextBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel Margin="4,0,4,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value1, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ToolTip="{Binding Path=Hint, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox x:Name="TextField"                              
                          Margin="2,0,0,0"
                          Width="{Binding Path=ActWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                          Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibleAct, Mode=OneWay}"
                          GotKeyboardFocus="TextField_GotKeyboardFocus"
                          />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
private void TextField_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    lb2.SelectedItem = textBox.DataContext;
}
```

Comment: This is what I came up in the first second :) I intended to use it only with XAML as it may be a markup language only but it is a very flexible and strong markup language. I'm really sad that I can't do it with XAML.

Comment: I tend to disagree :). XAML is a markup language and not a programming language.

Comment: @Nestor Did you tried my solution? I think it can work

Comment: @sTrenat I tried with this but no change:   <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Mode=OneWay}" />

Comment: It just tries to keep the focus - if you use it with the initial trigger. Unfortunately, it is not enough.

Comment: I'm on my phone so i can't write full solution, but it couls lools like:  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode="OneWay", RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

Comment: But IsKeyboardFocusWithin is required only once - when the user clicks the TextBox.The binding to its relative self looks like works okay, I just forgot to tell the Path. @sTrenat if you create an answer with your suggestion, I will accept that.

Comment: @Nestor Can you give me 2 hours? I don't have time right now :P

Comment: Sure :) Thanks for helping to prove the power of XAML :P